# Issue with Partial View name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi I am stuck in to a code i don't no whats wrong I have done.
This is what I am getting in error block.

[image]

This is function call

```
function GetDocumenttList(FID, CID) {
    var fURL = "/ClaimEdit/AllDocumentList";
    if (FID && CID) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: fURL,
            dataType: "html",
            async: false,
            data: { "folderID": FID, "claimID": CID, "page": 1 },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (result) {
                $('#partialdivDocumentList').html(result);
                $('#partialdivDocumentList').css('display', 'block');
                //....Now update Navigation List start.
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '/ClaimEdit/NavigationList',
                    datatype: "text",
                    async: false, data: { "parentID": FID, "claimID": CID },
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#divNavigationList').html(result);
                    }
                });
                //....Now update Navigation List end.
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                alert(request.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is view "AllDocumentList.cshtml"

```html
 @model PagedList.IPagedList<CRM.Core.ViewModel.Claim.ClaimDocumentViewModel>
    @using PagedList.Mvc;
    <table class="table-grid-3" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="60%">
                    Document
                </th>
                <th width="20%">
                    Date
                </th>
                <th width="20%">
                    User Name
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Ajax.ActionLink(item.ClaimDocumentName, "DocView", new { claimDocID = item.ClaimDocumentID, path = item.ClaimDocumentPath + item.ClaimDocumentName }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "divPartidalDocView", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ClaimDocumentUploadDate)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("AllDocumentList", new { page, folderID = ViewBag.folderID, claimID = ViewBag.claimID }), PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "partialdivDocumentList" }))
```

And last this is my Action.

```
public ActionResult AllDocumentList(int folderID, int claimID, int? page)
{
    ViewBag.folderID = folderID;
    ViewBag.claimID = claimID;
    Mapper.CreateMap<ClaimDocument, ClaimDocumentViewModel>();
    var folderList = _ClaimDoc.GetClaimDocumentListByFolderIDClaimID(claimID, folderID);
    var folderListModel = folderList.OrderBy(x => x.ClaimDocumentID).ToList();
    var pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
    return PartialView(folderListModel.ToPagedList(pageNumber, Common.Constants.PageSize));
}
```

I am stuck wiith this error where my partial view AllDocumentList not able to find out, while searching its adding **" \u0027"**
I am not a hunk in MVC so please bare me if ask some thing silly.

Comment: Don't comment on your own question, please update it instead.

Comment: @AvneeshSrivastava is your AllDocumentList.cshtml view stored in the ~/Views/ClaimEdit folder?

Comment: No the location of AllDocumentList.cshtml is "~\Areas\Claims\Views\ClaimEdit\AllDocumentList.cshtml"

Comment: Is that your default position for all views?

Comment: If you are not using the default view engine structure of MVC, [this](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Creating_a_Custom_View_Engine_in_ASPNET_MVC.aspx) link might be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

From your comment I see that your View is living in an Area, but the error message shows that it is being called or searched from a non-Area location (i.e. the root of the website).

There are two things to try:

- Make sure that the Controller is also in the Area, and that the URL contains the Area.
- Or if that can't be done or is not what you need, then you may need to move the view into the `/Views/Shared` folder.

Comment: Hi controller is also in same area. I can access other partial view having action in this controller.
I don't want to shift view to shared folder.

Answer (score -1):

\u0027 refers to a single quote..You should try to encode the string or use JSON.NET which sends the encoded strings as it is.

Comment: ...can you give some more details

Comment: Pls use something like      var test=JSONObject.escape(yourstring)

Comment: var fURL =JSONObject.escape("/ClaimEdit/AllDocumentList)";

Comment: its showing in console "ReferenceError: JSONObject is not defined"

Comment: Please reference the json2 library in your script,  - https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

Comment: but why its happening I just want to call a action and use HTML return by action to update a div.

Answer (score -1):

Finally I am now able to over come this scenario. I know its not the good practice but till I get any right response I'll like to use this trick.
I am using full Path for my partial view.
Some thing like:

```
  return PartialView("~/Areas/Claims/Views/ClaimEdit/AllDocumentList.cshtml", folderListModel.ToPagedList(pageNumber, Common.Constants.PageSize));
```

Still I'll wait if some one have better solution of this. I am also not aware why in action I have to give full path of partial view (In this control only else where I am not having such type of issue)